# Showing $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)=0$ for $n\in\Bbb{N}-\{1\}$, while still maintaining geometric intuition

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

## Problem

Given that $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$$
Proof that $f(x) \equiv 0, \forall n\in \mathbb{N} - \{1\}$

---

## Context

I need to prove this to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(x +\frac{2\pi k}{n}) = 0,\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\forall n\in \mathbb{N}-\{1\}$. This has use cases in 3 phase AC circuits (where $n = 3$) so that you can use it as ground ($Voltage = 0$) but it turns out that this equation is also true for all positive integers bigger than $1$.[Graph with slider to see that it is equals 0](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bafmdfd6pl)

$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(x +\frac{2\pi k}{n})$ can be broken down by:
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(x +\frac{2\pi k}{n})\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin x\cos \frac{2 \pi k }{n} + \cos x \sin\frac{2 \pi k}{n}\right)\\
=&\sin x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\cos \frac{2 \pi k }{n}\right) + \cos x \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{2 \pi k }{n}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$

The proof that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{2 \pi k }{n}\right)$ is very straight forward and intuitive which uses a similar technique to when you proof that $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{Let } J = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{2 \pi k }{n}\right)\\
J = &\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{2 \pi k}{n}\right)&(1)\\
J = &\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{2 \pi \left(n - 1 - k\right)}{n}\right)\\ 
= & \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin2\pi\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{k}{n}\right)\right)\\
= & \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(2\pi - \frac{2\pi}{n} - \frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\\
= & -\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (1 + k)}{n}\right)\\
= & -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}&(2)\\
&\text{Take } (1) + (2)\\
&2J = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{2 \pi k}{n}\right) - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}&(2)\\
&2J = \sin x + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{2 \pi k}{n}\right) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{2 \pi k}{n}\right) - \sin\left(x + \frac{ 2 \pi n}{n}\right)\\
&2J = \sin x - \sin x = 0\\
\therefore & J = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{2 \pi k }{n}\right) = 0\\
\end{align}
$$

And if you sketch it on the unit circle, you can easily see that everything will cancel out nicely but for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\cos\frac{2 \pi k }{n}\right) = 0$, it's a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to see this is that $f(n)= \Re \sum_{k=1}^n \zeta^k$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity.  These powers of $\zeta$ are precisely the roots of $z^n-1$, and the sum of the roots of any $n$th degree polynomial (in $\Bbb C$) is the negative of the coefficient of $z^{n-1}$.  Since that coefficient is $0$ in $z^n-1$ (assuming $n \gt 1$), we have that $\sum_{k=1}^n \zeta^k=0$, so that sum also has real part $0$.  (Incidentally, looking at the imaginary part also tells you the result is $0$ for $\sin$ as well as for $\cos$.)

Answer (score 0):

> Given that $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$$
> Proof that $f(x) \equiv 0, \forall n\in \mathbb{N} - \{1\}$

Let $~\displaystyle z = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right).~$

Then, by [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

$$\left[ ~\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) ~\right] + i\left[ ~\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) ~\right]$$

$$= 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots + z^{n-1} = \frac{1 - z^n}{1-z} = 0.$$

This implies that both the real and imaginary components are equal to $~0.~$

So, what you end up with is that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) = 0,$$

and

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way. Is it correct?

$$\frac n{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z^n}{z^n-1}dz\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos(\tfrac{2\pi k}{n})+i\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(\tfrac{2\pi k}n)=0$$
since the residue at infinity is zero.